# How to measure multithread performance/capacity in a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, http

I'm using Windows Forms and HTMLAgilityPack to Load a website HTML into a variable, with Parallel.For to call it 10 at a time.

How can I calculate how many times I could do this in Parallel? Watching task manager CPU usage? I'm I calling to few or too many times?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, For and ForEach will utilize however many threads the underlying scheduler provides, so changing MaxDegreeOfParallelism from the default only limits how many concurrent tasks will be used.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your help! Increasing MaxDegreeOfParallelism and running let's say 100 concurrent tasks at a time, How would I know 100 is a good number? With CPU usage? Is there a relation of the CPU cores to the quantity of possible threads?

Comment: TPL automatically determine the best number of threads based on the cores/processors in the hosting machine. You shouldn't worry about it unless you have a real problem and needs to decrease the automatic calculated value

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to determine what degree of parallelism (how many threads) yields the best performance?
I'd recommend

- Don't worry about it unless you determine that performance is actually an issue. You can fine tune it but the perfect settings on the computer you're using might not be so great on another where the code executes.
- Perform multiple tests and see which concludes faster. Back before we had `Parallel.ForEach` I would do that sometimes. I often found that adding more threads meant faster execution, and then adding some more produced diminishing returns or even slower performance.

Unless you're seeing performance issues and you think this is the fix I wouldn't worry about it.